# Can a finite value for $\int_1^\infty \exp(x^2)\,dx$ be defined?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, divergent-series

Why should
$$\int_1^{\infty}\exp(ix^2)dx,\int_1^{\infty}\exp(-ix^2)dx,\int_1^{\infty}\exp(-x^2)dx$$
converges but not:
$$\int_1^{\infty}\exp(x^2)dx$$

Is there any way that assigns a value to $\int_1^{\infty}\exp(x^2)dx$ which is consistent with the three former? (similar to $1+2+3+...=-\frac{1}{12}$)

EDIT: By suggestions from Nate, I think I should point out that I'm interested in the analytical continuation of $z\rightarrow \int_1^{\infty}\exp(zx^2)dx$. Does it exist? Does it have application in other fields?

Comment: Hint: Look at the graph of $\exp(x^2)$

Comment: It is worth noting that the equation you allude to ($1+2+3+\cdots =-1/12$) is misleading.  The sum does not actually converge to that, but the analytic continuation of the function $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{n^s}}$ to $s=-1$.  There are plenty of answers on this site that address this with greater detail.

Comment: @Hayden: So maybe the OP would like to know about the possibiility of analytically continuing the function $z \mapsto \int_1^\infty \exp(zx^2)$ which is certainly defined and analytic on $\operatorname{Re} z < 0$?

Comment: I suspect the downvotes are because your title was annoying people.  I changed it.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, I brought it up with the hope that it would clarify what the OP wanted.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying me :)

Answer (score 2):

Why? Because the integrands of the first two are oscillating trigonometric functions, whose positive parts cancel out their negative ones in such a way that the final result is finite. $~$ The third one is a powerfully decreasing, and therefore convergent, exponential function. The last one is a powerfully increasing exponential function, diverging towards infinity.